# Deleted Old Versions Still Appear

Tags: box-api

I am using the following API methods to try and keep only one version of my files:

Upload a New Version of a File
POST https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/FILE_ID/content

View Versions of a File
GET https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID/versions

Delete an Old Version of a File
DELETE  https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID/versions/VERSION_ID

However after deleting old versions of a file, if I run View Versions again I can still see the same number of versions (and version ids) available, with no indication that they have been removed. If I try and delete them again I get an error ("Unable To Delete File")

How do I determine if an old file version has already been deleted?

FYI: I have disabled the Trash option in the Admin Console.

Ideally what I would like is to disable versioning so that only the latest version of a file is kept.

Comment: that looks like a bug.  We should have a fix out shortly.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the response Peter - Does shortly mean within a day, a week, a month? Just so I know if I need to work around the issue.

Comment: probably closer to a couple weeks